# Exchange Web Services (EWS) possible server URLs

Tags: email, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm working on an application where the user logs in to his Exchange account. To save the user some monotony, I want to implement so that the entire URL of the server the user belongs to doesn't have to be given.

E.g

```
mail.domain.com
```

would result in

```
https://mail.domain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx
```

However, I can't find if it is safe to asume that all possible URLs will end in "/EWS/Exchange.asmx". Is that so? Or do I have to try all the possible combinations I can come up with, to see if it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jason pointed out, you can not know for certain that the EWS resides at /EWS/Exchange.asmx, so I ended up implementing the following:

1. Convert the URL on the form `mail.domain.com` to `https://mail.domain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx`
2. Try this URL. If it doesn't work, try to Autodiscover.
3. If this doesn't work either, notify the user and ask him to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use autodiscover and retrieve the server name from the returned XML.
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463896%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

You can play with autodiscover in Outlook - Ctrl + right click on the Outlook icon in the tray area, select "Test E-mail AutoConfiguration".

Comment: I have an option to Autodiscover, which works great, but it takes a long time. I want to get away with that by making the user writing the server URL himself, but not the entire thing. I'm just wondering if the server URL can be arbitrary, or if there is some kind of pattern that is always fulfilled.

Comment: You could always try appending that to the server they give you to see if it works, then fall back on Autodiscover if not. AFAIK it does always end in /EWS/Exchange.asmx, but I suppose if someone *really* wanted to they could create their own VDIR that uses a different pattern to serve EWS calls.